# how to get a particular field from web activity output in azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a pipeline where I want to store a particular value from a web activity in azure data factory, in a variable, so that I can pass it to other activities.
I want to get the export ID but I keep running into errors.
The response of the web activity looks like this:

```
{
    "requestId": "----",
    "result": [
        {
            "exportId": "---",
            "format": "CSV",
            "status": "Created",
            "createdAt": "2020-12-15T16:03:01Z"
        }
    ],
    "success": true
}
```

I have tried the following methods but it fails: @string(activity('Web1').output.result.exportId

@string(activity('Web1').output.result[0].exportId

@string(activity('Web1').output.result.[0]

first(@string(activity('Web1').output.result)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhXoM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7xmS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this. Your second expression should work `@string(activity('Web1').output.result[0].exportId)`

My test

Output of Web activity

[image]

These expressions also work fine on my side, you can have a try:

```
@string(activity('Web1').output['result'][0]['exportId'])
@string(activity('Web1').output.result[0].exportId)
@string(first(activity('Web1').output['result']).exportId)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
@string(json(activity('Web1').output.response)[0]['Id'])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.